# How can I name a variable dynamically in awk?

Tags: shell, unix, nawk, awk

I have requirement where first "n" rows ("n" being variable passed at run time) should be stored  in "n" corresponding arrays, array name being named as `arrayRow"NR"`; here, `NR` is the built-in awk variable.

```
awk -F"," -v n=$Header_Count 'NR<=n{
split($0,**("arrayRow" NR)**) }' SampleText.txt
```

So the first row should be stored in array `arrayRow1`; the second row should be stored in `arrayRow2`, ... etc. Any ideas on how to create dynamic array name in awk?

Comment: If you have gawk, you should look into an array of arrays instead.

Comment: Maybe use multidimensionale arrays https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Multidimensional

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it without a hacky shell loop and bad coding practices for letting shell variables expand to become part of an awk command, or a function that populates hard-coded, predefined arrays given a numeric arg or similar. Don't even try it.

If you have or can get GNU awk you should use true multi-dimensional arrays instead:

```
$ cat file
a b c
d e
f g h
i j k
l m

$ awk -v n=3 '
NR<=n {arrayRow[NR][1]; split($0,arrayRow[NR]) }
END {
    for (i in arrayRow)  {
        for (j in arrayRow[i]) {
            print i, j, arrayRow[i][j]
        }
    }
}
' file
1 1 a
1 2 b
1 3 c
2 1 d
2 2 e
3 1 f
3 2 g
3 3 h
```

Otherwise you can use pseudo-multi-dimensional arrays in any awk:

```
$ awk -v n=3 '
NR<=n { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) arrayRow[NR,i] = $i; nf[NR]=NF }
END {
    for (i in nf) {
        for (j=1; j<=nf[i]; j++) {
            print i, j, arrayRow[i,j]
        }
    }
}
' file
```

but you don't actually need multi-dimensional arrays for this at all, just use 1-dimensional and split the string into a new array when you need it:

```
$ awk -v n=3 '
NR<=n {arrayRow[NR] = $0}
END {
    for (i in arrayRow)  {
        split(arrayRow[i],arrayRowI)
        for (j in arrayRowI) {
            print i, j, arrayRowI[j]
        }
    }
}
' file
```

Comment: Hi Ed, Am able to solve the problem. It is really helpful. Thanks a lot.